# Connection Timeout Expired without apparent network issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, connectivity, vmware

We have one particular SQL Server which is intermittently timing out when accepting connections.  The issue is consistent throughout the day, but occurs at a very low incidence.  How can I continue to troubleshoot?

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=0;
>   handshake=15002;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

Server Configuration:

- SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU5 Enterprise (issue also occurred prior to SP1)
- Windows Server 2012 R2 on both server and client
- VMware ESXi, 6.5.0 on HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9
- VM has 8 vCPU, 64 GiB of memory (fully reserved)

Test Script (executed once per second):

```
$failed = $false;
$loginDuration = (Measure-Command {
    $ncon = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection `
        @( 'Data Source=1.2.3.4,16143;Database=Test;User=Test;Password=****;Pooling=false;' );
    try 
    {
        $ncon.Open();

        $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand `
            @( 'SELECT @@VERSION', $ncon );
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        $ncon.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        $failed = $true;
    }
}).TotalMilliseconds;
Write-Metric -metric 'itp.dbserver.logintime' -unit 'milliseconds' `
    -value (&{if ($failed) { 120000 } else { $loginDuration }});
```

Observations:

- Issue started occurring after OS Updates, SQL Server Updates, San move, and move from Hyper-V to VMWare
- Most connections succeed (4 failures out of 1,440 attempts)
- Failures are always listed with a low number in "[Pre-Login] initialization=0;" and a high number in "handshake=15002".  We do not get errors like "Not found" or "No such host is known", only "Connection Timeout"
- No encryption is enabled for the listener
- Pings show no loss over extended period (0 lost out of 96,045 sent)
- All firewalls are disabled
- Connections attempted using IPv6 and IPv4 addresses fail at the same rate
- CPU is low-ish (<40%)
- Active sessions is persistently around 400
- Balloon driver is disabled
- Connections once made are stable, no unexpected errors when executing queries, no odd disconnections.
- Multiple clients are having problems connecting - both ODBC and ADO from multiple computers

*Update:* I finally got a client-side Wireshark trace of a failed connection.  No packet loss is apparent, client receives TCP ACK's in real-time (<10ms).  Client was using DNS name at time of failure, but failure does occur using the IPv4 address in the connection string.

[image: Wireshark conversation graph showing server not responding for >15 seconds]

Am I correct in thinking that the fact that I get immediate TCP ACK's to the pre-login request packets sent would localize the issue to the OS or SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was eventually identified as a side-effect of VMWare LRO.  Disabling host-based LRO resolved the issue.  See

- [Enable or Disable LRO on a VMXNET3 Adapter on a Windows Virtual Machine](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-ECC80415-442C-44E9-BA7A-852DDB174B9F.html)
- [Large Receive Offload](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-514BC149-CDE7-4E07-A922-E3DFB663DC13.html)
- [Poor network performance or high network latency on Windows virtual machines (2008925)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2008925)
- [vmxnet3 adapter on windows server 2012 with MSSQL server bottleneck problem](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/524842)