# Intermittent failures to connect to 127.0.0.1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, windows-server

I have an instance of SQL Server 2016 (13.0.4451) which I can reliably connect to over shared memory (`lpc:(local)\instance`).  If instead I try to connect to `127.0.0.1,1433` I experience low (~1/1000) failure rates with the error message:

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=3; handshake=14995;

What would affect the loopback connection, but not the shared memory connection?

<sup>Related, but far more broad: [Connection Timeout Expired without apparent network issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188255/connection-timeout-expired-without-apparent-network-issue)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is already quite old, I won't bother asking you to clarify the problem, and will instead try to focus on providing some things that might be worthwhile looking at, that some future visitor might find helpful.

- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5 and 4.5.1 have a known issue with [connections to localhost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.5-4.6#attempting-a-tcpip-connection-to-a-sql-server-database-that-resolves-to-localhost-fails)
- It's possible your server is suffering from thread-starvation.  Confirm the maximum number of expected simultaneous connections, including pooled connections that might not be actively performing tasks is [below the maximum number of threads for your server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017).
- Confirm there are no network-related filters in place that might be dropping connections.  Running `netsh winsock show catalog` will show the base service providers and any [layered service providers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) that might be interfering with connectivity.  Particularly look for anti-virus or firewall apps.
- Check network utilization, and if necessary [tune networking parameters for performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn567662(v=vs.85).aspx).
- If SQL Server is running in a virtual machine, check the host server to ensure a memory reservation has been set that prevents memory being swapped out ([VMware](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.vsa.doc_10/GUID-8AE3622F-A657-4D02-9F6C-34A53C5B1C51.html), [Hyper-V](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualpfe/2011/08/29/hyper-v-dynamic-memory-and-host-memory-reserve-setting/)).  Ensure a CPU reservation has been set to prevent the virtual machine being starved of processing power.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this will be helpful to someone.  This particular issue ended up being [caused by VMWare](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207510/16496).